# Simple groups in group theory

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is an abelian simple group then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some prime $p$. What if $G=\{e\}$ the trivial group?

Comment: Simple groups are non-trivial: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group

Comment: The trivial group shouldn't be simple for the same reason that $1$ shouldn't be prime: that would break the uniqueness of composition factors, in the same way that $1$ being prime breaks the uniqueness of prime factorization.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan On reading this quickly, I read the $1$ as an "I", which caused me to stop for a second.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, a simple group is nontrivial by definition.

> A *simple group* is a nontrivial group whose only normal subgroups are the trivial group and the group itself.

Therefore $G \neq \{e\}$.

Comment: A cleaner way to state the definition is that a simple group is a group which has exactly two normal subgroups. This is similar to how you can define a prime number to be a positive integer which has exactly two positive integer factors. See also http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/too+simple+to+be+simple.